# Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub

Tags: java, android, json, stream, bufferedreader

Can someone explain what the "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! exception is? This error is being generated when I try to read a Json object in the following method:

```
 public void getEvent() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, JSONException {
    //Read object, take string and convstruct new JSon object
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null || line.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Done");
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            buf.append(line);
        }
    }
    if (buf.length()==0) {
        System.out.println("NOTHING IN JSON");
        return null;
    }


    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(buf.toString()); // Here is where the error is generated 
}
```

Here is the stack Trace:

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:7)
   at edu.carleton.l8server.JSONEventSource.getEvent(JSONEventSource.java:57)
  at edu.carleton.l8server.ThreadWithReactor.run(ThreadWithReactor.java:37)
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: what does `buf.toString()` contain? Is it valid JSON? Please provide stacktrace and value of buf.toString()

Comment: Stack Trace provided.